# Android - Shared Preference with Two Classes

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Basically I want to set up one class to have getters and setters to the device to store and retrieve data, and other classes to access it. I managed to get sharedpreferences working in one class but having trouble with two classes (I'm familiar with Java but not Android, I read somewhere I shouldn't be using Activity but static, and couldn't get that working either). Anyway here is the getter / setter class.

```
public class Storage extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "uk.co.kenreid.examplestory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String nameKey = "uk.co.kenreid.examplestory.name";
```

I access it with these pieces of code in the other class (final is used as the variable "storage" is used within an onclicklistener):

```
final Storage storage = new Storage();

storage.storeItem("name", name);
System.out.println(storage.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is initialising the `SharedPreferences` away from the `Activity`?

Assuming this is your issue, you can pass a `Context` through the constructor of the `Storage` class to initalise it.

Eg.

```
SharedPreferences prefs;

public Storage(Context aContext){
    prefs = aContext.getSharedPreferences("uk.co.kenreid.examplestory", 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Then access via your original acessor methods. Might be best to pass the `Application Contex`t rather than `Activity Context` through to the constructor, so when you create your Storage class, call it like this in the Activity:

```
Storage myStorage = new Storage(getApplicationContext());
```

It might be wise to create a **Singleton** class as well, to allow you to use the same instance of Storage. There are plenty of tutorials for Singletons in Java around the web.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("uk.co.kenreid.examplestory", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Comment: Cheers for the response but no luck with this. Still getting the following error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main .... Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(uk.co.kenreid.examplestory/uk.co.uk.kenreid.examplestory.start): hava.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Storing something in shared preference:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("TOT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
    Editor ed = prefs.edit();  
    ed.putString(key, value);  
    ed.commit();
```

In your case you could use the above code inside the onCreate method.

Fetching something from shared preference:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("TOT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.getString(key, null);
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply but I have this working in theory (as I mentioned I got it working in one class, it's specifically the parameter passing / starting activity / using static context I'm having trouble with).

Comment: Ok got it. if you are starting the storage activity just to access the shared preference data then you dont need to. You can access it outside an activity just by passing the context. Secondly you are starting activity the wrong way. To start an activity instance do this: Intent intent = new Intent(context, Storage.class); startActivity(intent). Note: if you are starting activity from a non activity class, you will have to pass a context to that class and then you could start it like this: context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Sayed - thank you for helping me, you were correct with the first point you made but someone else actually wrote that part out in code which I used and fixed the issue but I wanted to personally thank you for the help also and give you a vote up. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

mVariable = sharedPref.getBoolean(SettingsActivity.KEY_TO_VARIABLE, false);
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I'm getting an error on getActivity() saying it's undefined for type Storage (class name).

Answer (score 0):

check the doc of [getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Here the first parameter is the namem of the Shared Preference where you are storing the data. So you need to use the same name from every classes to access the same shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate class can handle all your preferences

```
public class PreferenceManager {
    public static void setLogInSuceess(boolean login, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        preferences.edit().putBoolean("LOGIN", login).commit();
    }

    public static boolean getLogInSuceess(Context context){
        SharedPreferences preferences;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean login = preferences.getBoolean("LOGIN", false);

        return login;
    }
}
```

Use it where ever you want,

PreferenceManager.setLogInSuceess(true/false, context);
boolean _login = PreferenceManager.getLogInSuceess(context);

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Storage extends Application
```

Application is a class used to share data from Activities

Comment: You can comment your evalutation please? I see the class Application in the Scrumptious example of Facebook SDK where in my opinion is used to share data from different Activity.